# I am not gettin how to get rid of error here

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node()
    {
        data = NULL;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

Node* insertBST(Node* root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        root->data = value;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    if ((root->data) > value)
        insertBST(root->left, value);
    if ((root->data) < value)
        insertBST(root->right, value);
}

Node* printBST(Node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        printBST(root->left);
        cout << "\n" << root->data;
        printBST(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node* root = new Node;
    insertBST(root, 30);
    insertBST(root, 20);
    insertBST(root, 40);
    insertBST(root, 70);
    insertBST(root, 60);
    insertBST(root, 80);
    printBST(root);
}
```

Above is the code which I wrote to implement Binary Search Tree. When I execute it, the program stops responding and closes. I tried getting help from pythontutor.com but I am not able to tackle it.What should I do to make it run without error?
here is where it stops : [Click to see](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Node%0A%7B%0Apublic%3A%0A%20%20%20%20int%20data%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Node%20*left,*right%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Node%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3DNULL%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20left%3Dright%3DNULL%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0ANode%20*searchBST%28Node%20*root,int%20search_value%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28root-%3Edata%3D%3Dsearch_value%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20root%3B%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28root-%3Edata%3Esearch_value%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20searchBST%28root-%3Eleft,search_value%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20searchBST%28root-%3Eright,search_value%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ANode%20*insertBST%28Node%20*root,int%20value%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28root%3D%3DNULL%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20root-%3Edata%3Dvalue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20root-%3Eleft%3Droot-%3Eright%3DNULL%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20if%28%28root-%3Edata%29%3Evalue%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root-%3Eleft,value%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28%28root-%3Edata%29%3Cvalue%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root-%3Eright,value%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0ANode%20*printBST%28Node%20*root%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28root!%3DNULL%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printBST%28root-%3Eleft%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cout%3C%3C%22%5Cn%22%3C%3Croot-%3Edata%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printBST%28root-%3Eright%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint%20main%28%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Node%20*root%3Dnew%20Node%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,30%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,40%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,70%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,60%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20insertBST%28root,80%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20printBST%28root%29%3B%0A%7D%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=15&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=cpp&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Any help is appreciated,I am new to writing program.

Comment: We need an error to work with. If you run this in a debugger, you should be given an actual error message.

Comment: I am not able to resolve the error.

Comment: `insertBST` never allocates new nodes. The second insertion should have given you a segfault.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes, second insertion is giving error. how to deal with that?

Comment: Read up on BST insertions and try again. It looks like you don't completely understand it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In `insertBST` in the case of `root == NULL` you do not create a new node and attempt to modify the contents of `root`, as this is null it should result in an access violation or segmentation fault.

I think the reason your program is hanging instead of crashing is that you are using an online compiler that ignores invalid writes and instead allows the program to continue. This then possibly ends up with infinite recursion through the `insertBST` function.

To fix this you need to allocate a new node, one way would be as follows:

```
void insertBST(Node*& root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node();
        root->data = value;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    if ((root->data) > value)
        insertBST(root->left, value);
    if ((root->data) < value)
        insertBST(root->right, value);
}
```

Note that your program leaks all the nodes that it allocates. You should write a destructor in `Node` which deletes all child nodes and call `delete root` at the end of your program. Alternatively don't use raw pointers at all and use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @new_Coder please consider accepting this answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: I am not able to print the BST correctly. the output is: 0 30 20 40 70 60 80. But the expected output is: 30 20 40 70 60 80

Comment: @new_Coder your question was how to make your code run without an error. There was no mention of the expected behaviour/output.

Comment: When I run the code I get the numbers in order which is what I'd expect the output to be